# How to mount multiple disks in a loop using ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, mount, disk, rhel7

I just started working with Ansible recently. I am trying to mount 4 disks on azure VM which were attached using terraform. Each disk was passed with a LUN number and I am fetching the device name(sdc,sdd etc.) for each disk using that LUN no.and grep.

```yaml
    - name: get volume name
      shell: echo "/dev/$(ls -l /dev/disk/azure/scsi1 |grep {{ item.lun }}|egrep -o "([^\/]+$)")"
      register: volumename
    - parted:
        device: "{{ volumename.stdout }}"
        number: 1
        state: present
    - filesystem:
        fstype: xfs
        dev: "{{ volumename.stdout }}"
    - mount:
        fstype: xfs
        opts: noatime
        src: "{{ volumename.stdout }}"
        path: "{{ item.mountpoint }}"
        state: mounted
    - command: blkid -s UUID -o value {{ volumename.stdout }}
      register: volumename_disk

    - blockinfile:
        path: /etc/fstab
        state: present
        block: |
          UUID={{ volumename_disk.stdout }}   {{ volumename.stdout }}      xfs defaults,noatime,nofail 0 0

      loop:
        - { lun: 'lun0', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql/binlog', diskname: 'binlog' }
        - { lun: 'lun1', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql/innodb', diskname: 'innodb' }
        - { lun: 'lun2', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql/data', diskname: 'data' }
        - { lun: 'lun3', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql', diskname: 'backup' }
      tags: test
```

I keep getting volumename variable is not defined error. Is there any way to set volumename as global so that the next playbook can access it or How I can improve this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through documentation, I was able to find a way to achieve this.

The right approach would be to use Ansible's dictionary variable.

```html
raid_config:
  - lun:          "{{ backup_lun }}"
    mountpoint:   "{{ backup_mountpoint }}"
  - lun:          "{{ data_lun }}"
    mountpoint:   "{{ data_mountpoint }}"
  - lun:          "{{ binlog_lun }}"
    mountpoint:   "{{ binlog_mountpoint }}"
  - lun:          "{{ innodb_lun }}"
    mountpoint:   "{{ innodb_mountpoint }}"
```

Moved the tasks to a separate file mountdisk.yml and passed a dictionary to the tasks like this

```html
- include_tasks: "mountdisk.yml"
  loop: "{{ raid_config }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: disk
  tags: test
```

This way I was able to fetch lun and mount point as disk.lun and disk.mountpoint.
Note: you would need to pass tags keyword separately in each task (if you are using one)while using include_tasks option.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'm not an expert with ansible, but what it look like you're trying to do is:

- Use the same loop for multiple tasks.

Which I think is not possible. The other thing is that the `loop`-variables is only available to the task with matching indentation, in your case: `blockinfile`.

What you can do is create an own *task*-file for the tasks you want perform and include that in your playbook (loop over includes).
This has been done by @Konstantin in following example: [Multiple ansible task with same loop](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/2979)

**EXTRA:**
[Reason why it is NOT available](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13262)
IF it had been possible to use a single `loop` for several tasks, then you would have to make sure to apply it to all the tasks, like:

```yaml
- block:
    task1
     ...
    task2
     ...
  loop:
    - { lun: 'lun0', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql/binlog', diskname: 'binlog' }
    - { lun: 'lun1', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql/innodb', diskname: 'innodb' }
```

---

**EXAMPLE:**

(Created an example from your comment, I do not think this is a good solution, but it is a solution)
Create a list using `set_fact` and then pass this list to another playbook.
Using my existing examples:

**my_tasks.yml**:

```yaml
---
- command: echo "{{ item.lun}}"
  register: volumename
- set_fact:
    volumenames: "{{ volumenames|default([]) + [ { 'name': volumename.stdout } ] }}"

- debug:
    msg: "VOLUMENAME is: {{ volumename.stdout }}"
```

**playbook.yml**:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_tasks:   my_tasks.yml
      loop:
        - { lun: 'lun0', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql/binlog', diskname: 'binlog' }
        - { lun: 'lun1', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql/innodb', diskname: 'innodb' }
        - { lun: 'lun2', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql/data', diskname: 'data' }
        - { lun: 'lun3', mountpoint: '/apps/mysql', diskname: 'backup' }

- import_playbook: playbook2.yml myvar='{{ volumenames }}'
```

**playbook2.yml**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ myvar }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and yes you are right include_tasks would only be the way to loop over multiple tasks but the issue remains the same as loop is passing dynamic variables like "lun" and builds a variable volumename which needs to be further used in the tasks and Ansible does not seem to be good at that. Not sure if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: Not sure if I follow. You can of course use set_fact to create a new variable, which can be use by another playbook. ( I can add  a less usable example using debug to see if it's understandable) –

Comment: Your solution below is way better. Thank you.